# Android App won't write to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and Android Studio to build an app. I have a register screen that asks the user for things such as username and location etc. When the register button is clicked, the users' email and password work and show up in the authentication tab in the Firebase Console. However, I cannot get the users details such as username and location, to store in the Firebase Realtime Database.

```
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText emailReg, passwordReg, password2, roleReg, officeReg;
    Button regButton;
    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    EditText usernameReg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        emailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
        usernameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regUsername);
        passwordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
        regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_Button);
        password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);
        roleReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regRole);
        officeReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regOffice);
        databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
    
    public void registerUser() {
        final String email = emailReg.getText().toString();
        final String password = passwordReg.getText().toString();
        String pass2 = password2.getText().toString();
        if(!pass2.equals(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Passwords Do Not Match",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
        }
        //Code taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start on 10/11/2019
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            Intent intent_signup = new Intent(register.this, home.class);
                            startActivity(intent_signup);
                            finish();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication Successful!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });

    }


    public void registerOnClick(View view)
    {
        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                registerUser();
                insertDataDB();

            }
        });


    }

    public void insertDataDB()
    {
         String username = usernameReg.getText().toString();
         String office = officeReg.getText().toString();
         String job = roleReg.getText().toString();
         String email = emailReg.getText().toString();


        String id = databaseUsers.push().getKey();

        Users user1 = new Users(username, office, job, email);
        databaseUsers.child(id).setValue(user1);


    }

}
```

Users.java

```
package com.example.securityapp;

public class Users {

     String username;
     String job;
     String email;
     String office;

     public Users()
    {

    }

    public Users(String username, String job, String email, String office)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.job = job;
        this.email = email;
        this.office = office;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getJob() { return job; }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public String getOffice()
    {
        return office;
    }



}
```

---

[image]

This is the notification I am receiving but I am not using Cloud Firestore, I am trying to use Realtime database

Answer (score 0):

Change the security rules to the following :

```
{
  // Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
  // Warning: **NEVER** use this ruleset in production; it allows
  // anyone to overwrite your entire database.

  "rules": {
    ".read": true
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I already have these set up and still no luck :(

Comment: The method `insertDataIntoDb` should be inside `createuserwithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: Ive tried moving the insertDataDB method into here also, and still nothing :( Im really confused as to what is going on. A friend has her code the exact same as mine, and hers seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

Once you finished creating the account by using `mAuth`, you should store the data location, etc in the Firebase.

```
//Code taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start on 10/11/2019
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

        // Here we will get the user information, ex userUid (optional)
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //After that store the data before intent to next activity
        insertDataDB();

        //Then proceed to next activity
        Intent intent_signup = new Intent(register.this, home.class);
        startActivity(intent_signup);
        finish();

        Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
        Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // ...
}
});
```

UPDATED:
Store method.

```
 public void insertDataDB()
 {
        String username = usernameReg.getText().toString();
        String office = officeReg.getText().toString();
        String job = roleReg.getText().toString();
        String email = emailReg.getText().toString();
        String id = databaseUsers.push().getKey();

        Users user1 = new Users(username, office, job, email);
        databaseUsers.child(id).setValue(user1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                //Success store data in database.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                //Something happened
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I move the insertData(); method to be before the intent, I still get the same issue. The Authentication is successful but the details do not store in the realtime database?

Comment: @ChloeHamilton have you check the security rules for Realtime Database?

Comment: yes my rules for the database are set to read true and write true

Comment: @ChloeHamilton I think it went to exception. !task.isSuccessfull() . Update your setValue(user1).addOnSuccessListener

Comment: how do you mean? Do I just add .addOnSuccessListener to the last line of the insertData method? - Thanks :)

Comment: @ChloeHamilton check my answer, I already updated new answer.

Comment: have you this error before? Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
My app was able to correctly register users and now I am getting this error and my app is no longer working. The only thing I changed is I used the firebase assisstant and added the dependencies

Comment: @ChloeHamilton I've never had this error before. What is firebase assistant? what dependencies did you add?

Comment: I am unable to open my project now. It says fatal error initializing Gradle GUI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205479/discussion-between-ticherhaz-and-chloe-hamilton).